# Bypassing akamai

Tags: vbscript, akamai

I am completely new to Akamai. I have a .vbs file, which get served by Akamai. Recently operation team put restriction in .vbs, so now it is getting blocked. Is there a way to get this file served directly from web server and bypass Akamai?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's possible. Even if you add few rules in akamai configuration and bypass akamai for .vbs extension, request will still have to go through akamai servers. Best option is to give it a try in Akamai staging env or contact akamai support.

Answer (score 0):

If this file is updated frequently and should not be cached at all, then the best option would be to setup Akamai configuration to have this file as no-store, or if you need only specific requestors to be able to reach your own infra, behind Akamai, then bypass the Akamai cache. Still it will go through Akamai.
If the issue is going through Akamai, your only solution is to have another hostname not on Akamai to reach this file OR to know what is the server on your infra, which hosts this file and modify your host file to request this server directly. Issue is that the whole site will be served from your infra and not benefit of Akamai.